# Solve $t y''(t) +2 y'(t) - ty(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I have been trying to solve the differential equation $t y''(t) +2 y'(t) - ty(t)=0$ through the Frobenius method. WolframAlpha says the solution should be $ y(t) = c_1 \frac{e^{-t}}{t} + c_2\frac{e^t}{t}$. I got that $r=0 \lor r=-1$. For $r=0$, we get that $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$, so $a_{2k}=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}$, but this will not get me the correct solution. Could anyone try to solve it and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: what is $r$ in this question?

Comment: The solution is of the form $y(t)= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n t^{n+r}$ by Frobenius method.

Comment: The substitution $y=tz$ makes it into $z''-z=0$, which is constant coefficient equation. Why do you insist on the Frobenius method?

Comment: This question was given to me by someone else, from what they told me they were asked to solved by Frobenius in specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake in your calculations. As you derived the solution is actually given by
$$
y(t)=a_0\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\,.
$$
Note that since
$$
\sinh t=\frac{e^{t}-e^{-t}}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\,,
$$
hence you found the totally legitimate solution
$$
y(t)=a_0\frac{\sinh t}{t}\,.
$$

To reconcile it with the solution given by Wolfram Alfa just note that the linear combination of $e^t/t$ and $e^{-t}/t$ gives you exactly your solution.

Since the second value of $r=-1$ (you did find it also correctly), and hence your $r$'s are divided by integer, Frobenius method does allow you to find a second linearly independent solution to your problem. It can be done, however, using any of the standard methods of reducing the order of your ODE (or using Abel's formula).

Comment: The Frobenius method does handle logarithmic and pseudologarithmic cases. The recurrence relation corresponding to $r = -1$ is $a_{k + 2} = a_k/((k + 1) (k + 2))$, with no additional initial conditions. Taking $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 0$ and $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$ gives two linearly independent solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not typing. This is a solution without Frobenius method!
[image]

Comment: How did you find this transformation? What is thought process that leads one to pick this transformation out of the infinite number of possibilities? Was it just trial and error or did you use some known method/algorithm to find it?

Comment: It is one of the first tricks to try$ y=zt^{m}$